# calling Jquery Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently following a tutorial and the person in the tutorial is coding css, html, and jquery all in one file. I split them up into seperate files. My problem is the code in the tutorial works when calling a function and mine does not, even though the code is exactly the same. Here is some of my code

```
//Jquery File

function username(){
    $("#container").html("<span class = 'bot'>Chatbot: </span>Hello, what is your name?");
}


$(function(){

username();

    $("#textbox").keypress(function(event){

........
```

HTML File

```
<div id = "container">

</div>

<div id = "controls">
.....
```

Tutorial Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function username(){
    $("#container").html("<span class = 'bot'>Chatbot: </span>Hello, what is your name?");
}

$(function(){

    username();

    $("#textbox").keypress(function(event){

.......
```

It's exactly the same but for some reason my code does not work, I tested out both. And i know I'm linking to the correct jQuery files because my other function work fine no problem.

Full HTMl
        
    
        JQuery Chatbot Tutorial

## jQuery Chatbot v. 1.0 Tutorial

```
<div id = "container">

</div>

<div id = "controls">
    <textarea id = "textbox" placeholder = "Enter your message here..."></textarea>
    <button id = "send">Send</button>
    <br>
    <input checked type = "checkbox" id = "enter"/>
    <label>Send on enter</label>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chatbot.js"></script>
</body>
```

Full JQuery File

```
function username(){
    $("#container").html("<span class = 'bot'>Chatbot: </span>Hello, what is your name?");
}



$(function(){

username();

    $("#textbox").keypress(function(event){
        if ( event.which == 13){
            if ( $("#enter").prop("checked") ){

                $("#send").click();
                event.preventDefault();

            }

        }

    });
        });


    $("#send").click(function(){

        var username = "<span class ='username' = >You: </span>";

        var newMessage = $("#textbox").val();

        $("#textbox").val("");

        var prevState = $("#container").html();

        if (prevState.length > 3){
            prevState = prevState + "<br>";
        }

        $("#container").html(prevState + username + newMessage);

        $("#container").scrollTop($("#container").prop("scrollHeight"));

    });
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console window?

Comment: can you show us the html code

Comment: in case sometimes when calling a function with the same name as a input name it will not work and it doesn't show you any errors

Comment: Are you sure you included jQuery before this JS code?

Comment: The console is clear with no error @sushil

Comment: Yes @theFX i have other working functions so

Comment: Can you provide the entire code so people can help take a look? It would be easier for your to use http://jsfiddle.net and provide a link.

Comment: So i tried it on jsfiddle.net(http://jsfiddle.net/h54d70Lp/1/) and it works,  but why is not working on my browser?

Answer (score -2):

You might have error in the code before the call. Try:

```
$(function(){
  alert('Debug me 2');
  username();
  alert('Debug me 2');
...
```

and see what happens.